# Firebase Analyticsの設定における`verbatim`とは？

Tags: swift, ios, firebase

既存のiosアプリでadmobを使用しています。
sdkを最新にしたところ、firebase analyticsのフレームワークももれなく入れることになり、
折角なのでAnalyticsの機能も使ってみようと、現在設定中です。
GoogleService-Info.plistをプロジェクトに追加し、以下のコードをAppDelegateクラスに追加してみました。

```
import FirebaseAnalytics //追加
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //〜省略〜

    FIRApp.configure() //追加
    return true
}
```

↓のサイトでは`verbatim`や`endverbatim`の記述もあるのですが、これらを入れるとエラーになるので外しているのですが、`verbatim`とは何でしょうか？
外した状態でビルドはできているのですが、この他に記述すべきコード等があればお教えください。

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start
[image: アプリにAnalyticsを追加する]

Comment: 英語表記時にはないものなので、単にソースコード部分を翻訳対象から外すために存在しているものが、誤って見えている状態なのだと思います。

Comment: 表示がおかしくなっているということなのですね。